# Deserialize FORM hierarchical structure to JS object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, serialization

I have a *form* with controls that have **names representing a hierarchical structure**.

#### Example

```html
<form>
    <input name="[field1][0][field11]" value="foobar1" />
    <input name="[field1][0][field12][0][field121]" value="foobar2" />
    <input name="[field2]" value="foobar3" />
    <input name="[field3][0][field31]" value="foobar4" />
    <input name="[field3][1][field32][0][field321]" value="foobar5" />
</form>
```

I want to obtain an **Object** representing the hierarchy, like this:

```js
{
    "field1": [
        {
            "field11": "foobar1",
            "fiedl12": [
                {
                    "field121": "foobar2"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "field2": "foobar3",
    "field3": [
        {
            "field31": "foobar4"
        },
        {
            "field32": [
                {
                    "field321": "foobar5"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

How to obtain that? Is there any native JS or *jQuery* function to achieve this? (*.serializeArray()* is not helping here)

---

Just the name structure is standard, the actual names will not have indexes like *field-**12*** or *field-**321*** (the only indexes are into the second square brackets of the pattern "**[field][index]**".

**[field]** corresponds to a normal string value (when no *[index]* is present) or to an array (when the *[index]* is there).

**[index]** always corresponds to a new **Object** (`{}`) having the properties defined in the following `[]`-brackets set.

PS - Please no *jQuery* plugins

Comment: ugly whey to do something

Comment: what is the difference from [field3][0] and [field3][1]? why isn't [field1][0] the same?

Comment: **[field3][0]** is a new {}-object (with the _field31_ property), in the array **[field3]**. **[field3][1]** is a another {}-object (with the _field32_ property), in the same array. And **[field1][0]** is a third object into the **[field1]** array (that is a different property than the array **[field3]**).

Answer (score 0):

Not too difficult.  First get an array of elements, split the names, then recursively put them into an object.  Then output the object and you have what it sounds like you want.

I will admit though, this is quite messy and I am guessing there is probably a much better way to do whatever you are trying to do.  Either way, the below code should work for what you described.

**note:** This uses plain javascript with no Jquery or other libraries.

```js
function organizeInputs() {
  var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');  // Get all input elements
  var output = {};
  for (var i=0;i<inputs.length;i++) {           // Iterate through elements
    var keys = inputs[i].name  // Split and format element names to keys
      .split("]")
      .map(function(str) {
        return str.replace("[", "");
      }).filter(function(str) {
        return str.length > 0;
      });
    fillObj(output, keys, inputs[i].value);  // Recursively add to object using keys
  }
  return output;
}

function fillObj(obj, arr, val) {  // Recursively add to object passed
  if (arr.length == 1)
    return obj[arr[0]] = val;
  if (!obj[arr[0]])
    if (arr.length > 1) {
      if (isNaN(arr[1])) {
        obj[arr[0]] = {};
      } else {
        obj[arr[0]] = [];
      }
    } else {
      obj[arr[0]] = {};
    }
  return fillObj(obj[arr[0]], arr.slice(1, arr.length), val);
}

//  To use run organizeInputs()

//  Just for display
var out = document.createTextNode(JSON.stringify(organizeInputs(), null, 2));
document.getElementById("result").appendChild(out);
```

```html
<form>
  <input name="[field1][0][field11]" value="foobar1" />
  <input name="[field1][0][field12][0][field121]" value="foobar2" />
  <input name="[field2]" value="foobar3" />
  <input name="[field3][0][field31]" value="foobar4" />
  <input name="[field3][1][field32][0][field321]" value="foobar5" />
</form>
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not so easy as it looks like. Collecting all elements, parse the name and iterating over the new object with distinct view on array or object children. Then apply value.

```js
function getForm(form, object) {
    var a, e = form.elements, i, l;
    for (i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
        a = e[i].name.match(/([^\[\]]|\[\])+/g);
        l = a.pop();
        a.reduce(function (r, k, j) {
            r[k] = r[k] || (isFinite(a[j + 1] || l) ? [] : {});
            return r[k];
        }, object)[l] = e[i].value;
    }
}

var object = {};
getForm(document.forms.form1, object);
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(object, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

```html
<form name="form1">
    <input name="[field1][0][field11]" value=" foobar1" />
    <input name="[field1][0][field12][0][field121]" value="foobar2" />
    <input name="[field2]" value="foobar3" />
    <input name="[field3][0][field31]" value="foobar4" />
    <input name="[field3][1][field32][0][field321]" value="foobar5" />
</form>
```